# BC30456: 'DataItem' is not a member of 'System.Web.UI.Control'?

Tags: html, asp.net

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptEarnings" runat="server">  
 <ItemTemplate>     
 <table style="display:<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "TS_ALLOW_IND")%>">

                                           </ItemTemplate>
                                        <FooterTemplate>
                                            </table>
                                        </FooterTemplate>
                                    </asp:Repeater>


 <div class="panel-footer" style="display:<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ALLOW_NEW_SAVE")%>">
                           <input type="button" value="New" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" onclick="fn_newRecord()" />
                        <asp:Button ID="btnSave" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" OnClientClick="return fn_save();"
                                                    runat="server" Text="Save all" />
                                            </div>
```

I'm passing a value for display in style property for a table and a div, for table my code is working but when it comes to div I get  'DataItem' is not a member of 'System.Web.UI.Control' error.

I don't get error when I tried replacing it with `<%# Eval( "ALLOW_NEW_SAVE" ) %>`  but I don't get value either and ALLOW_NEW_SAVE has a value( I replaced  TS_ALLOW_IND which worked). Any ideas?

Comment: Can you edit your question and post the markup of the containing data-bound control for both elements?

Comment: IS THIS WHAT YOU NEED?

Comment: Your `<table>` and `<div>` tags will be contained within a data-bound control - a `ListView`, a `Repeater`, a `DataList`, or something else. You need to specify which data-bound control you're using, and which template of that control your tags are in.

Comment: Ohk..thats the problem I guess div doesn't have any data-bound control..How to add one? I tried adding asp:Repeater which didn't work